# Sharing Photo and Copying String to Instagram Stories

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, uipasteboard

I have an app that allows a user to share to an image to IG stories. My problem is, I can't seem to simultaneously copy a url string from which a user can then paste as an IG Link sticker.

I couldn't find any existing solution and any thoughts would be appreciated.

I tried setting the pasteboard string to the urlString in the completion handler for `UIApplication.shared.open` to no avail.

My code:

```
func share(_ sender: Any) {
 
if let urlScheme = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme), let pngImage = backgroundImage.pngData() {
    
    UIPasteboard.general.string = "urlString"
    
    let pasteboardItems = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage": pngImage]]
    let pasteboardOptions: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey: Any] = [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]
    
    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteboardItems, options: pasteboardOptions)
    UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme)
}
```

Comment: ```"com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL" : "link"```. try passing another pasteboard item with above key.

Comment: @uditha it does not work

Comment: yeah it seems like they have removed that feature. Their documentation also does not says anything about link sharing. But it used to work with ```contentURL```

Comment: Did you figure out a workaround for this?

Comment: @DipoAreoye unfortunately no, literally have tried everything. i have seen other apps achieve this though, so im not sure what is necessarily different/missing...